# How to find/detect any textarea in page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to put a function call in my pages called enableTinyMCE(); In that function I want to see if there are any textarea's in my page and if so do the tinyMCE.init() function.  How do I detect if there are any textarea elements in the page?

Comment: Why does 
<textarea>jhg</textarea>
<textarea>fgh</textarea>
$('textarea').length
result in 4?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you only want to know whether or not there is at least one.

Comment: ok. if the $('textarea').length > 0 i need to include the <script src="..." /> how does that work?

Comment: You could put something like this inside the if statement: $.getScript("myFunction.js", function() {
      alert('script loaded');
   });
See http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if( $('textarea').length > 0 ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if($('textarea').length > 0) {
    document.write('we have at least one textarea');
}
```

OR

```
if($('textarea').length) {
    document.write('we have at least one textarea');
}
```

Read this, from the FAQ:

http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F

Answer (score 5):

It is worth noting that the functionality you are looking for can be handled by TinyMCE itself:

If you set the `mode` parameter to `textareas` in your tinyMCE.init() call, it will automatically convert any textareas it finds to editor instances. If there's no textareas, it won't do anything, quietly.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    mode : "textareas",
    ...
});
```

Conversely, you could tell TinyMCE to convert only textareas that match a CSS class name by using the `specific_textareas` value to the `mode` parameter.

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   mode : "specific_textareas",
   editor_selector : "mceEditor"
});
```

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/mode

Answer (score 4):

To expand on karim79 answer.

From the [jQuery docs page](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F): Note: It isn't always necessary to test whether an element exists. The following code would show the item if it exists, and do nothing (no errors) if it did not.

Which that means is that you can just do:

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").each(function(i){
        this.enableTinyMCE();
    })
})
```

**Edit:**

There is actually a jQuery plugin being developed for this purpose. I would download and try out the plugin and contribute to it's development if you can.

[jq-tinyMCE](http://dev.jquery.com/wiki/Plugins/tinyMCE)

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery selector always returns an array even if no matching elements are found. This means that you need to check the length.  Try this instead.

```
if($('textarea').length > 0) {    
 document.write('we have at least one textarea');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following as suggested however I still only want to call enableTinyMCE if there are textareas in my page. I cannot call this function in document.ready. See Google! Any ideas?

```
$(function() {

     if ($('textarea').length > 0)
    {
       var data = $('textarea');
       $.each(data, function(i)
       {
         tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, data[i].id);
       }
       );
    }

});

function enableTinyMCE()
{
        tinyMCE.init({
            plugins: 'paste',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
            theme_advanced_buttons1: 'pastetext,pasteword,copy,cut,separator,bold,italic,underline,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,undo,redo,separator,link,unlink,separator,charmap,separator,formatselect,separator,code',
            theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
            theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
            mode: 'textareas',
            theme: 'advanced',
            theme_advanced_blockformats: 'None=p,Heading 3=h3,Heading 2=h2'
        });
}
```

the tinymce.init needs to be called outside of documentready but $('textarea').length is always zero outside of documentready. Help!

Comment: why does the tinymce need to be called outside of document.ready? the document.ready is to make sure the DOM is registered by the browser

Comment: I have found this - http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2008/06/09/setting-up-tinymce-with-jquery-and-cakephp-12 but I am doing it dynamically so I don't know the id of the textareas. Also what if you have more than one textarea

Comment: the jquery selector that you're using ($('textarea') doesn't look for id. It looks for all tags that textarea

Comment: read the article. i need to pass an id to the tinymce command

Comment: I have never used TinyMCE before, but since it looks like its a javascript function, there is nothing wrong with having it in the document.ready bracket. As far as the textarea situation, if you're having it check outside the document.ready then it will return 0 because it looks for textarea tags before waiting til the document has loaded therefore; it will not find any unless the textarea tag is before you check, which is why it should be in document.ready to make sure all tags all loaded

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
if ($('textarea').length > 0)
    {
       var data = $('textarea');
       $.each(data, function(i)
       {
         tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, data[i].id);
       }
       );

       $('form').bind('form-pre-serialize', function(e) {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave(true,true);
        });
    }
```

And to enable tinyMCE I have done this

```
<% if (ViewData["TextAreaVisible"] != null && bool.Parse(ViewData["TextAreaVisible"].ToString()) == true)
   {%>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           enableTinyMCE();
        </script>
<%} %>
```

EnableTinyMCE does this

```
function enableTinyMCE() {

    tinyMCE.init({
        plugins: 'paste',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
        theme_advanced_buttons1: 'pastetext,pasteword,copy,cut,separator,bold,italic,underline,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,undo,redo,separator,link,unlink,separator,charmap,separator,formatselect,separator,code',
        theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
        theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
        mode: 'none',
        theme: 'advanced',
        theme_advanced_blockformats: 'None=p,Heading 3=h3,Heading 2=h2'
    });
```

}